# Wordpress menu - css selector issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a custom menu on a page:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-148 publish">
       <a href="http://url/site/index.php/products/product-name/">Information<span class="circle">•</span></a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-149 publish">
       <a href="http://url/site/index.php/products/product-name/register/">Register<span class="circle">•</span></a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-150 publish">
       <a href="http://url/site/index.php/products/product-name/support/">Support<span class="circle">•</span></a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-151 publish">
       <a href="http://url/site/index.php/products/product-name/downloads/">Downloads<span class="circle">•</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Information is the parent page of the other 3

I have the following CSS, but it isn't recognised at all, it doesn't show up in fire-bug as being overridden, it just doesn't seem to exist, but not sure why?

```
.current_page_ancestor > a,
.current-menu-ancestor > a  { border: 1px solid red; color: red; background-color: blue; }
```

If I remove `.current-menu-ancestor >` from the CSS then the styles effect all the links as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS change:

```
current_page_ancestor
```

To:

```
current-page-ancestor
```

But make sure to check out wordpress cusom menu walker.

It will have the sub items inside a new `ul` which is nicer and better for seo.

Comment: Thanks, did not notice the underscores, that's interesting because I copied the css styles from the Wordpress Twenty Thirteen theme, and checked and the typo was there :/

Comment: I know the feeling xd

Answer (score 0):

I would use this instead, it's also how I style WordPress menus in theme development.

*Target the main navigation > child > child of child*

```
#menu > li > a { border: 1px solid red; color: red; background-color: blue; }
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/rOqKdN)

**OR**

```
.current-page-ancestor > a  { border: 1px solid red; color: red; background-color: blue; }
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/yYREqd/)

Comment: And how would you check if it is the current ancestor? This does not resolve his problem nor answers his question. Although I agree with the way you do the menu styling.

Comment: His question was his CSS was not recognized, nor his styles being placed on the DOM elements. It didn't show up in firebug either, not how to check if it is the current ancestor.

Comment: True but the reason why it didn't show up in firebug was because he made typo

Comment: ty for letting me know